# How to save settings inside a textfile using Discord.Js

Tags: discord.js

How can I save some settings inside a text file or is there a better way to save settings by using a command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common practice is to setup a `config.json` files with your Discord token (and some other thing you need, like your prefix, a duration for a timeout, etc):

```
{
  "token": "<Discord  bot token>",
  "avatar": "https://i.imgur.com/ezC66kZ.png",
  "prefix": "!"
}
```

then require the file at the  beginning of your program like this:

```js
const config = require("./config.json");
```

You will then use it like this:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", setActivity);
client.login(config.token);


function setActivity(){
  client.user.setActivity(config.prefix + "help"); // here !help
}
```

Comment: @Waldre Don't forget to keep this config private (because of the token). If you're putting your code on a git (or anything else) you can include a `config.json.sample` with what the config should look like. You **have** to set your token somewhere (in code / file / db) and it's easier to store the rest of the settings alongside it. In the db is a choice, but less easy to do (you need to insert it by hand or with a script). A json file is totally fine. You can keep it and don't change it. If you're looking to store edited data during the execution of the bot the db will be better for those data

Answer (score 0):

Saving settings in a txt or json file is not recommended as they tend to be corrupt after time. You should look into using a database.

Comment: Looking into it at the moment I just wanted to check something before I save a huge amount and then what I had planned isn't working the way i thought it would, but thank you for the idea